# Multisig for Bitcoin ordinals wallet

Tags: multi-signature, ordinals

I am trying to make and receive transactions on Unisat wallet, but Unisat doesn't support multisig. How do I implement multisig for a wallet that supports ordinals?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Sparrow Wallet for this. It is documented in the official `ord` [documentation](https://docs.ordinals.com/guides/collecting/sparrow-wallet.html).